# ServiceStack Locode Forms.formData is undefined

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to customize the UI for the edit form. While referring the chinook repo's [custom.js](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/Chinook/blob/main/Chinook/wwwroot/modules/locode/custom.html) file,

`this.apiState.apiForm(Forms.formData(this.$ref.form, this.apiState.op))`

is throwing

```
Uncaught TypeError: Forms.formData is not a function
    at Proxy.submit (GetFlags?new=true:4635:35)
    at eval (eval at We (petite-vue.js?vfx=6.2:1:8737), <anonymous>:3:26)
    at HTMLFormElement.i (petite-vue.js?vfx=6.2:1:8122)
```

Though the locally installed the `servicestack/ui` package's `shared.d.ts` file contain the type definition `formData`, except this function all other functions are available inside the `Forms` type.

Anything wrong I am doing?

--Raaj

Comment: Forms is a variable so it's likely it didn't initialize properly have a look at JS for any previous errors, otherwise try upgrading to the latest [v6.3.1+ on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) as it contains some fixes.

Comment: I just checked the code from the ServiceStack source file and found this resolving the issue, `this.apiState.apiForm(new FormData(this.$refs.form))`